# android studio says my android table is at sdk api 1

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio says my android tablet, where I want to debug, is at sdk api 1 (deviceSdk(API 1), my minSDKVersion= '14' in the project manifest, but my tablet device says it is at Android 4.4.2, so Studio says the device is incompatible.  What am I missing?

Comment: Obviously AS has not (yet) recognized your device. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) and make sure you took all the necessary steps. (activated developer options on device?)

Answer (score 1):

I turned off "USB debugging" on the tablet, and back on.  Got some message about the device and AS sharing some kind of security key. I said ok, then the device was now enabled and all is as it should be.

Thanks for the help